# How to build my own rpm file via omnibus, for example td-agent rpm

Tags: rpm, yum, fluentd, treasure-data

**What I'd like to do:**

I'd like to run two versions of td-agent on CentOS 7.x.

So, I'd like to register both default `td-agent` and `td-agent-my-own` in my yum repo server.

And, for that, I'd like to create my own rpm file of td-agent; `td-agent-my-own`.

**What I did:**

So far, I downloaded [omnibus-td-agent](https://github.com/treasure-data/omnibus-td-agent),

and I edited `omnibus-td-agent/config/projects/td-agent2.rb`.

I tried to build with some commands and some other procedures, but got lost.

**Question:**

How do can I build my own td-agent, named `td-agent-my-own`.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely looking for [rpmbuild](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/rpmbuild.8.html) (which is the "proper" way to put together your own RPMs). However, that can be a little complicated... particularly for newcomers. For a quick fix, you can just use [FPM](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) (Called "Effing Package Manager") -- it's a pretty quick-and-dirty script which allows you to essentially supply a file list and some descriptive items, and be done with it.